# how to use cshtml files with durandal - The Generic controller approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, durandal

I am a noob with Durandal and web MVC, so bear with me... :-)

I have researched this thread: [How can I use cshtml files with Durandal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981833/how-can-i-use-cshtml-files-with-durandal/15636715#15636715)

I have check at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539354/2261129

But it requires a dynamic controller with an action per view, I am working in a project with 100+ views so this is not going to work.

I am very intrigued about this answer from Maarten:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636715/2261129

But I am in doubt in how to use this from Durandal?

Can anybody help me get started please??

help is greatly appreciated...

tak/gracias/thanks!

O

Answer (score 0):

I actually preferred the first answer from Young, even though he preferred Maarten's.  Using Young's answer, you could use .NET MVC routing to set up your views.  Let's say I have a home view, about view, and other view.  I could set up the routing like so:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DurandalHome",
    url: "dynamic/home",
    defaults: new { controller = "RealHomeController", action = "Index" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
name: "DurandalAbout",
url: "dynamic/about",
defaults: new { controller = "RealHomeController", action = "About" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
name: "DurandalOther",
url: "dynamic/other",
defaults: new { controller = "OtherController", action = "Index" }
);
```

Obviously this would be a pain because you would have to do this for your 100 views, but that would prevent the need to change the physical locations of your views.  I imagine the same could be done using the viewLocator or viewEngine on the durandal side, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: Just a note.  You can use regular expressions to match routes.  Not sure if this will fit the scenario but its nice to know.