# Trying to inject the result from an MVC controller into a Durandal view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, durandal

I'm trying to inject a partial MVC 4 view into a durandal view. The MVC view contains a Kendo grid which I would like to include a bit like using compose in durandal.
Looking at [How can I use cshtml files with Durandal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981833/how-can-i-use-cshtml-files-with-durandal/15636715#15636715) did not enlighten me enough I'm afraid.

Does anyone have any further insight they would like to share? How would I include the MVC view in my durandal view?
I.e. my durandal /App/views/home.html should somehow include the result from my MVC view /Views/Data/index.cshtml

Comment: I would recommend watching John Pappa's series on SPA's: http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=single-page-apps-jumpstart&highlight=john-papa_spajs-m5-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, watching the SPA course and reading this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/hpfZB-WFEXk helped solved my issue.
I ended up using Youngs approach, it was only when I saw the example I finally understood...