# Hottowel or Kendoui SPA with kendo ui library?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, durandal, kendo-asp.net-mvc, hottowel

I am planning to start a new project where i am planning to go for SPA route.

As i am goint to use Kendo ui , I have two choices with me either to use Hottowel and use [Architectural advice for a SPA ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953315/architectural-advice-for-a-spa-asp-net-application)  or to go for Kendo UI SPA.

I have been working with HotTowel SPA for couple of months now. However, i see Kendo ui SPA doing things a bit differently.

Can anyone who has good exposure of both of the framework suggest me which one should i opt for considering project to be complex with many modules and pages ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to think about is what you're wanting to do - you're planning on doing your whole work in JavaScript in a Single Page Application... when you think about it, how much .NET are you actually using there? That's right, just the server-side.

I'd look up Durandal SPA (which uses Knockout JS, Require JS etc by default, it's a sort-of boilerplate) in which you can still use Kendo UI MVVM with using the kendo-knockout.js library. Combine this with .NET MVC 4 (or 5 now!) for your Web API calls, that's what I've been doing on an enterprise level and absolutely love it.

As a side note, Durandal also provides a .NET project template which will get you up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine either way you go.  The advantages of using Kendo UI SPA are that it is fully integrated and aware of all of it's widgets, so it will do things like binding your views for you when you navigate to them.

The real question here I think is how to structure the application, and for that you really are going to want to be looking at RequireJS.  Neither HotTowl or the architectural advice are going to solve the problem of multiple javascript files that have dependencies on each other.

Check the following links...

http://requirejs.org/

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-05-08/requirejs-fundamentals.aspx

Full Disclosure: I work for Kendo UI and I believe it's a brilliant and simple stack.  However, you can use HotTowel or the architectural advice as suits your needs best.  Use what works best for you.

Comment: HotTowel, as far as I remember, does have RequireJS included within it and uses it throughout. Either way, great job with KendoUI - it's an awesome library.

Comment: Thanks for that!  True - and it looks like it uses Knockout as well so you can always use the Kendo Knockout Bindings http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/