# How to initialize the ViewModel from (partial) page in Durandal / ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, durandal

I've got [this approach (generating html files from cshtml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981833/how-can-i-use-cshtml-files-with-durandal).

And **Durandal's standard directory structure** (nothing special).

On some of my pages (*partial one*) I have the following (among others) (SubPage1.cshtml (referenced as 'SubPage1.html' in durandal)):

```
...
<select data-bind="event: { change: doSomething }, value: facilityId">
        <option value="0">Any Facility</option>

        @foreach (var facility in Data.CurrentUserFacilities())
        {
            <option value="@facility.FacilityId" selected="@CertainCondition">@facility.FacilityName</option>
        }
</select>
...
```

(`facilityId` is `ko.observable()` in my ViewModel code)

I fill data *dependently on current user's session*. That's *pretty convenient* to do with Razor. In this case I don't need the data from dropdown to be presented in my Durandal's ViewModel (I mean its whole list). However, I **do need the dropdown's selected value to be applied to ViewModel** (SubPage1.js) from the page (when the page is loaded).

What is the best way (and if there is any) to handle this situation?
I surely understand, that ideally I should load the page as a static one (just with Knockout bindings), then do some ajax request to server and then bind the data loaded. But, a) using Razor syntax is much more convenient and clean; b) that involves additional ajax request (and additional server logic).

---

Another approach I see is to notify the ViewModel about the page is loaded somehow and set (probably, manually via javascript) the facilityId current value. Like `<script type='text/javascript'> myViewModelIgetSomehow.facilityId(45); </script>`. But that also looks like not the best approach.

Any thoughts on that?

---

That's actually rather a question how to handle the last mentioned thought (**how to pass some values from the page loaded SubPage1.cshtml to ViewModel SubPage1.js**) not just how to handle Razor + Durandal ViewModel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be to create a custom binding for knockout. Here's a simple example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["serverCombo"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element);

        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var observableTarget = options.value;

        $element.change(function onElementChanged() {
            var newValue = $element.val();
            observableTarget(newValue);                
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element);

        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var observableTarget = options.value;

        $element.val(observableTarget());
    }
}
```

You could then use that binding as follows:

```
<select data-bind="serverCombo: { value: facilityId }">
    <option value="1">The Deck</option>
    <option value="2">The Pool</option>
    <option value="3">The Shagpile Carpet and Mirrored Ceiling room</option>
</select>
```

[Here's a fiddle which puts the whole thing together](http://jsfiddle.net/Km646/). Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you explain a purpose of 'update' part in this very case?

Comment: That will update the combo box if you change the value on the view model (after the page has loaded, for example). [Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Km646/1/) to show what the update part of the binding handler is used for.